# wget usage using batch file

Tags: batch-file, wget

I am trying to download a file using wget in batch file,I don't want to download the file if the file all ready exist and it didn't change so I am using `-N`
also I am downloading the file from my personal FTP server so I want to hide my **username** and **password** details so I decided to hide output using `>nul 2>&1`
so my batch file is:

```
@echo off
blah blah
.....
echo please wait...
wget -N ftp://XXXXXXXXXX@YYYYYYY.com/file.jpg >nul 2>&1
```

now there are 2 problems:

1. The window title will still show my username & password , how I can hide the title or   change the title ?
2. the user wont know if the operation was successful (download was done) or fail (no Internet or no file exist) or it didn't download because the file already exist , I wonder if I can make 3 IF STATEMENTS

   ```
   IF file was downloaded then echo file download

   IF file wasn't downloaded then echo error

   IF file wasn't downloaded because was the same then echo file didnt change
   ```

Comment: If the username/password data is sensitive, you should be using SFTP, not FTP. It's pretty trivial to intercept them with FTP. With SFTP, you can also use a key based login, and avoid needing to have them in plaintext in the script.

Comment: thanks for the advice , but I am giving the scripts to my friends and they don't know to sniff the password , also I am trying to make the batch more beautiful hiding the output

Comment: @Leo92 Can you please provide more detail about where the username and password should be hidden?

Comment: in the window title , when wget start ,in the title there is ftp://XXXXXXXXX:username@password.com/file.jpg

Comment: You are attempting to solve a problem the wrong way. You should never share your password in a BAT file. If the file you want to download should not be protected, then put it in a public folder of the FTP server. If the file must be protected and only accessed by few of your colleagues, then create different userids for your friends and let them to input the credential when trying to use your BAT file.

Comment: You could try moving the name and and the password to the corresponding command line options, `--ftp-user=username` and `--ftp-password=XXXXXXXXXX`.

Comment: if you're after only aesthetic/informational aspect you could use `title` in your batch - like in `title MY WINDOW TITLE`

Comment: @wmz it wont work because it will change the title in that moment

Comment: uh you're right wget specific (tries being helpful)... hush it with -q or -nv.

Comment: well, it does not show anything on my PC... it must be run via batch, though. Here is what I used as test: `wget -N -nv ftp://anonymous:none@ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.11.4.tar.gz`. I'm sorry it does not work for you

Comment: @wmz yes it will hide the title but it will show all things in window even that i use `>nul` to redirect it to nul , but its not working, anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with PA that if the file is sensitive then hiding the password in the console output won't do much in terms of security.  However, to answer the OP's question:

1.
The title command is capable of changing the current window's title.

```
title My CMD Window
```

If the problem you're encountering is that a popup window for the wget command is coming up and displaying the username and password there, you can use the following.  I apologize, I am not familiar with wget so I'm not sure on its behavior, hopefully this helps.

```
start "My WGET Window" wget -N ftp://XXXXXXXXXX@YYYYYYY.com/file.jpg >nul 2>&1
```

2.
A couple of checks before and after will be beneficial.  First, check if the file exists and don't even bother with the wget if it does already exists (assuming from the wording of your post that you do not want to overwrite the file).

```
if exist file.jpg echo File already exists!&pause&goto :EOF
:: run wget here
if exist file.jpg (echo File download successful.) else (echo File download UNSUCCESSFUL.)
```

We don't need to check for all three conditions as the file either exists before hand (in which case the batch exits) or it does not in which case we test for a successful download.  Note that it will be difficult to check for a partial file.

So, putting it all together:

```
@echo off
blah blah
.....
title My CMD Window
if exist file.jpg echo File already exists!&pause&goto :EOF
echo please wait...
start "My WGET Window" wget -N ftp://XXXXXXXXXX@YYYYYYY.com/file.jpg >nul 2>&1
if exist file.jpg (echo File download successful.) else (echo File download UNSUCCESSFUL.)
```

Comment: Consider using SFTP and a pair of keys to authenticate. That way you dont need to put the password in plain text. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031773/get-files-with-wget-and-sftp#14031977

Comment: I agree, using SFTP and not storing your password in the batch file is by far a better way to go.  However, from your link it seems like there is some complication in providing the key to the end users as well.  Assuming that problem is not insurmountable the extra security is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Wget has built in switches that will prevent a download if the file already exists. It has switches to do most of what you want so you won't have to put the "if" statements in the batch file at all.

wget has an extensive list of switches. Really it's dev has thought of just about everything. Read those docs, if I remember they are about 150-200 pages long.

Comment: Part of the OP's question was feedback regarding results of the wget.  I have to admit unfamiliarity with wget, it may provide feedback on what exactly it did, but by checking the file before and after running wget you set yourself up to accomplish the correct action for your particular application in each situation.