# get files with wget and SFTP

Tags: linux, wget, sftp

Hello guys...

I have a script running every night on a linux server, which intend to get files from another one using wget and ftp protocol. These files are located under a folder that can't be accessed through HTTP.

Here's the command line used :

```
wget --directory-prefix=localFolder ftp://login:password@adress.ip.of.server/path/*
```

The site access has been changed to SFTP. I would like to modify the script to be able to get the files just as it was doing before, but don't manage to do this with SFTP.

I tried to generate a secure key using ssh-keygen and then copy it to the server I wanted to access, but it didn't make it, or I just don't succeed to find the right way to do it...

Thanks ahead for your help ! :)

Comment: I don't think wget will help here. It does not support sftp. (nothing related to sftp listed in documentation). you might want to consider "curl"

Comment: Yes, I would totally deserve a nice RTFM. scp solved this, thanks to stackoverflow people, though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To copy keys, I find that `ssh-copy-id user@machine` does all you need. As long as you have a key on your machine that is.

I also use `scp` quite a bit, where you specify `scp user@machine:filespec whereto` (it is using the same encryption and authentication mechanism as sftp).

Hope this helps.

Comment: scp is different than sftp.

Comment: Yes, but if you have ssh access (presumably the user has), then it's a good alternative in most cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I used scp to solve this, and here is what I did : 

Created SSH key with ssh-keygen -t rsa. Transfered it with scp. Then in the script, connect without password and use scp again to get the files : scp login@adress.ip.of.server:/path/* /localPath/ 

Hope it will help someone, someday, somehow :)