# how do you get the tail -50 of the remote file in R

Tags: r

I need to be able to login to a system and get to get the tail -50 of the file. I have teh following set of code but this gets the whole file. Since the file is so huge, I need to run the script every 10 minutes and get the last 50 lines of the file. This is what I have:

```
library(RCurl)
for(k in 1:2) {
     day1<-day-k
     day1<-format(day1, "%Y%m%d")
     day_vector<-c(day_vector, day1)
}

servers<-c("ServerA", "ServerB","ServerC")

  for (i in 1:length(servers)) {
    for(j in 1:length(day_vector)) {
    ser_day<-paste(servers[i], day_vector[j], sep=".")
    url<-paste0(servers[i], ".example.net/opt/files/appl_log_")
    url<-paste(url, ser_day, sep="")
    url<-paste0("sftp://", url)

    tryCatch({

             x<-getURL(url, userpwd="account1:passwd1", connecttimeout=60)
             writeLines(x, paste0(servers[i], ".txt"))
            },error = function(e) 
            {
                    print("unable to get the file")

        })
```

Is there any way to get the tail of the file?

Comment: This is going to be difficult because you have to retrieve it via FTP, which precludes using any system-based tools.  You could use `wget` (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031773/get-files-with-wget-and-sftp) to pull down the file and then use Unix/Cygwin `tail` ...  Or use SSH tunnel to execute `tail` on the remote system?

Comment: Ben's second suggestion makes the most sense, but since you provided no information about the remote "system" there' not much more that can be done other than to refer you to your IT support staff.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, how would you do ssh with R?

Comment: I wouldn't, I would do it in the shell/at the OS level.  R is great, but it doesn't make sense to use it for everything (that is, I'm sure one could implement the ssh protocol in an R package, but it would be sort of crazy to do so if there is any possibility of using system utilities via `system()`)